# [Hackerrank][Performance Improvement] Similar Destinations

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I am currently solving a challenge that I found on **Hackerrank** and am in need of some assistance in the **code optimization/performance** department. I've managed to get my code working and returning the right results but it is failing at the **final** test case with a **timeout** error. The input is quite large so, that explains why the code is taking longer that expected.

Problem statement: [Similar Destinations](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/booking-hackathon/challenges/similar-destinations)

---

I've attempted to think of different ways of pruning my (intermediate) result set but could not come up with something that I did not already have. I believe that the `find` function could use a bit more tweaking. I've tried my best to reduce the number of paths that the recursive function has to take but ultimately, it has to look at every *destination* in order to come up with the right results. However, I did terminate a recursive path if the number of *tags* in common between *destinations* were below the `min` limit. Is there anything else that I could do here?

My code is as follows:-

```
  static class Destination {
    String dest;
    List<String> tags;

    public Destination(String dest, List<String> tags) {
      this.dest = dest;
      this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return dest;
    }
  }

  static List<Destination> allDest = new ArrayList<Destination>();
  static int min;
  static Set<String> keysTracker = new HashSet<String>();
  static Set<String> tagsTracker = new HashSet<String>();
  static Map<String, List<String>> keysAndTags = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  static void find(List<String> commonKey, List<String> commonTags, int index) {

    if (index >= allDest.size())
      return;

    if (commonTags.size() < min)
      return;

    if (tagsTracker.contains(commonTags.toString()) || keysTracker.contains(commonKey.toString())) {
      return;
    }

    String dest = allDest.get(index).dest;
    commonKey.add(dest);

    for (int i = index + 1; i < allDest.size(); ++i) {

      List<String> tempKeys = new ArrayList<String>(commonKey);
      List<String> tags = allDest.get(i).tags;
      List<String> tempTags = new ArrayList<String>(commonTags);
      tempTags.retainAll(tags);

      find(tempKeys, tempTags, i);

      if (tempTags.size() >= min) {
        if (!tagsTracker.contains(tempTags.toString())
            && !keysTracker.contains(tempKeys.toString())) {
          tagsTracker.add(tempTags.toString());
          keysTracker.add(tempKeys.toString());

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for (int j = 0; j < tempKeys.size(); ++j) {
            sb.append(tempKeys.get(j));
            if (j + 1 < tempKeys.size())
              sb.append(",");
          }
          keysAndTags.put(sb.toString(), tempTags);
        }
      }
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
    sort();
    calculate();
    answer();
  }

  static void init() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    min = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();

    String line;
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
      line = s.nextLine();
      if (line.isEmpty())
        break;
      String[] tokens = line.split(":");

      String dest = tokens[0];

      tokens = tokens[1].split(",");

      List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; ++j)
        tags.add(tokens[j]);
      Collections.sort(tags);

      Destination d = new Destination(dest, tags);
      allDest.add(d);
    }

    s.close();
  }

  static void sort() {
    Collections.sort(allDest, new Comparator<Destination>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(Destination d1, Destination d2) {
        return d1.dest.compareTo(d2.dest);
      }

    });
  }

  static void calculate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < allDest.size() - 1; ++i) {

      find(new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<String>(allDest.get(i).tags), i);

    }
  }

  static void answer() {
    List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> mapInListForm = sortAnswer();

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mapInListForm) {
      System.out.print(entry.getKey() + ":");
      for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); ++i) {
        System.out.print(entry.getValue().get(i));
        if (i + 1 < entry.getValue().size())
          System.out.print(",");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  static List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> sortAnswer() {
    List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> mapInListForm =
        new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>(keysAndTags.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(mapInListForm, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>() {
      public int compare(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e1, Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e2) {

        if (e1.getValue().size() > e2.getValue().size()) {
          return -1;
        } else if (e1.getValue().size() < e2.getValue().size()) {
          return 1;
        }
        return e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());

      }
    });
    return mapInListForm;
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You'd better to post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you don't have exact problem or issue you can't resolve.

Comment: Thanks, @VladimirVagaytsev. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem after a bit of selective profiling. It would seem that my initial hunch was right. The problem had less to do with the algorithm and more towards the data structures that I was using! The culprit was in the `find` method. Specifically, when calling the `retainAll` method on two `lists`. I had forgotten the that it would take O(n^2) time to iterate through two `lists`. That was why it was slow. I then changed `list` into a `HashSet` instead. As most of us know, a `HashSet` has an O(1) time complexity when it comes to accessing its values. The `retainAll` method stayed but instead of finding the intersection between two `lists`, we now find the intersection between two `sets` instead! That managed to shave off a couple of seconds off of the total elapsed runtime and all the tests passed. :)

The `find` method now looks like this:-

```
  static void find(List<String> commonKey, List<String> commonTags, int index) {

    if (index >= allDest.size())
      return;

    if (commonTags.size() < min)
      return;

    if (tagsTracker.contains(commonTags.toString()) || keysTracker.contains(commonKey.toString())) {
      return;
    }

    String dest = allDest.get(index).dest;
    commonKey.add(dest);

    for (int i = index + 1; i < allDest.size(); ++i) {

      List<String> tempKeys = new ArrayList<String>(commonKey);
      List<String> tags = allDest.get(i).tags;
      Set<String> tempTagsSet1 = new HashSet<String>(commonTags);
      Set<String> tempTagsSet2 = new HashSet<String>(tags);
      tempTagsSet1.retainAll(tempTagsSet2);
      List<String> tempTags = new ArrayList<String>(tempTagsSet1);

      if (tempTags.size() >= min)
        Collections.sort(tempTags);

      find(tempKeys, tempTags, i);

      if (tempTags.size() >= min) {
        if (!tagsTracker.contains(tempTags.toString())
            && !keysTracker.contains(tempKeys.toString())) {
          tagsTracker.add(tempTags.toString());
          keysTracker.add(tempKeys.toString());

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for (int j = 0; j < tempKeys.size(); ++j) {
            sb.append(tempKeys.get(j));
            if (j + 1 < tempKeys.size())
              sb.append(",");
          }
          keysAndTags.put(sb.toString(), tempTags);
        }
      }
    }

 }
```